# cannot acces to dependent variable after nesting for fitting lmer models

Tags: r, nested, nest, lme4

I have been trying to fitting such model

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(vs = factor(vs), gear = factor(gear), carb = factor(carb), am = factor(am), 
         cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% nest_by(vs) %>% 
  do(fit = lmer(.,formula= mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + (1 | am) +  (1 | vs)))
```

But unfortunately I am seeing that I cannot access to the cyl variable, as reported in the error I am getting.

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'cyl' not found
```

Can anyone just help me figuring out which the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: what library is the `lmer` package in?

Comment: in `lme4`. That is the is the one I am using, but if yous suggest to use the lmerTest maybe that would be changee the output

Comment: Not related to the question. But you may consider cleaning the call to mutate with `mutate(across(c(vs, gear, carb, am, cyl), \(x) factor(x)))` or just `mutate(across(c(vs, gear, carb, am, cyl), factor))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to embrace the tidyvrese and forget about the `do()`. You may also want to remove the `vs` variable in your model because you have chosen performing separate test for each group.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(broom.mixed)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(vs = factor(vs), gear = factor(gear), carb = factor(carb), am = factor(am), 
         cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% 
  # replacing nest_by with group_by
  group_by(vs) %>% 
  # either using nest_by or group_by, you may want to make sure that the "grouping variable" (vs) is not in the nested table
  # using group_modify is a cleaner way to do the job (with tidy)
  group_modify(~ broom::tidy(lmer(formula= mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + (1 | am), data = .x)))
```

FYI, if you insist using most of your code. You should let the do() know the input is the `data` column of the input data frame `.`.

```
test <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(vs = factor(vs), gear = factor(gear), carb = factor(carb), am = factor(am), 
         cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% nest_by(vs) %>% 
  do(fit = lmer(.$data,formula= mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + (1 | am) ))

test$fit
```